# How do you set up a confirmation prompt before running a playbook?

Tags: ansible

I want to install MariaDB after confirming user. I have a role and one simple task:

```
- name: install MariaDB
  yum: name: MariaDB state: present
```

or if I want to use `include: MySQL.yml`, if the user wants to, this line executes, if not skip this include.

```
- name: install MariaDB
  yum: name: MariaDB state: present

- include: MySQL.yml
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to use a var file yml 
& check variables in when statement of your yaml
example :

```
- name: Conditionally decide to load in variables into 'plans' when x is 0, otherwise do not. (2.2)
  include_vars:
    file: contingency_plan.yml
    name: plans
  when: x == 0
```

here when x = 0....

or you can set environnement variable before running ansibleplaybook & read it from

```
msg="{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}
```

to manage a local variable to be used in when statement

---

another method is prompting user for inputs from expect but this is not a good practice

```
- name: Case insensitve password string match
  expect:
    command: passwd username
    responses:
      (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
```

---

if not understood : here a real yes/no example :

```
---
 - name: Test from prompt
   hosts: localhost

   vars_prompt:
   - name: "check_mode"
     prompt: "Check mode: yes(default)=check-only, no=execute commands"
     private: no
     default: true

   tasks:
   - name: msg="False test | {{ check_mode }}"
     debug: var=check_mode
     when: not check_mode

   - name: msg="True test | {{ check_mode }}"
     debug: var=check_mode
     include yourfile.yml
     when: check_mode
```

Comment: thanks, @francois P but I understand yet. Should I put this code in the (`vars/main.yml`) file? 
`- name: Conditionally decide to load in variables into 'plans' when x is 0, otherwise do not. (2.2)
  include_vars:
    file: contingency_plan.yml
    name: plans
  when: x == 0`
if yes, how to check this in  `task/main.yml` ?

Comment: It's method examples not copy/past ready for your case only solution :)